# How substract millisecond with AWK - script

Tags: awk

I'm trying to create an awk script to subtract milliseconds between 2 records joined-up for example:

By command line I might do this:

Input:

```
06:20:00.120
06:20:00.361
06:20:15.205
06:20:15.431
06:20:35.073
06:20:36.190
06:20:59.604
06:21:00.514
06:21:25.145
06:21:26.125
```

Command:

```
awk '{ if ( ( NR % 2 ) == 0 ) { printf("%s\n",$0) } else { printf("%s ",$0) } }' input
```

I'll obtain this:

```
06:20:00.120 06:20:00.361
06:20:15.205 06:20:15.431
06:20:35.073 06:20:36.190
06:20:59.604 06:21:00.514
06:21:25.145 06:21:26.125
```

To substract milliseconds properly:

```
awk '{ if ( ( NR % 2 ) == 0 ) { printf("%s\n",$0) } else { printf("%s ",$0) } }' input| awk -F':| ' '{print $3, $6}'
```

And to avoid negative numbers:

```
awk '{if ($2<$1) sub(/00/, "60",$2); print $0}'
awk '{$3=($2-$1); print $3}'
```

The goal is get this:

```
Call 1 0.241 ms
Call 2 0.226 ms
Call 3 1.117 ms
Call 4 0.91 ms
Call 5 0.98 ms
```

And finally and average.

I might perform this but command by command. I dunno how to place this into a script.

Please need help.

Comment: Do you know how to make a `bash` script (or just a shell script in general)? That's the first step, where you can pipe together your `awk` commands.

Comment: Yes, I already did it and it works. But I just try to place it in a awk script, I tried but I couldn't understand how is the logical part.

Comment: one solution is to 'normalize' your hr:mm:ss to a seconds value and leave the ms part as a decimal fraction. Subtract those 2 values, and then un-normalize that value (left of the decimal) by back to hour, min, secs and then print as hh:mm:ss.ms. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter You're suggestion implemented sir!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
## For every input line.
{
        ## Convert formatted dates to time in miliseconds.
        t1 = to_ms( $0 )
        getline
        t2 = to_ms( $0 )

        ## Calculate difference between both dates in miliseconds.
        tr = (t1 >= t2) ? t1 - t2 : t2 - t1

        ## Print to output with time converted to a readable format.
        printf "Call %d %s ms\n", ++cont, to_time( tr )
}

## Convert a date in format hh:mm:ss:mmm to miliseconds.
function to_ms(time,    time_ms, time_arr)
{
        split( time, time_arr, /:|\./ )
        time_ms = ( time_arr[1] * 3600 + time_arr[2] * 60 + time_arr[3] ) * 1000 + time_arr[4]
        return time_ms
}


## Convert a time in miliseconds to format hh:mm:ss:mmm. In case of 'hours' or 'minutes'
## with a value of 0, don't print them.
function to_time(i_ms,         time)
{
        ms = int( i_ms % 1000 )
        s = int( i_ms / 1000 )
        h = int( s / 3600 )
        s = s % 3600
        m = int( s / 60 )
        s = s % 60
#       time = (h != 0 ? h ":" : "")  (m != 0 ? m ":" : "") s "." ms
        time = (h != 0 ? h ":" : "")  (m != 0 ? m ":" : "") s "." sprintf( "%03d", ms )
        return time
}
```

Run the script:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

Result:

```
Call 1 0.241 ms
Call 2 0.226 ms
Call 3 1.117 ms
Call 4 0.910 ms
Call 5 0.980 ms
```

Comment: I dont know how to say THANK YOU for everyone! Your post help me too much!

Comment: I see some hard to understand in this script, for example:
00:57:47.903
00:57:48.919

For this time the outcome should be 1.063 ms but the script prints 1.63 ms, very different. I dunno why it is doing that because only hours and minutes are declared to dont show 0.

Comment: I'm sry, those values 00:57:47.903 00:57:48.919 should show this value: "Call 1 1.016 ms" but it showing this value: "Call 1 1.16 ms".

Comment: @Martin_911: I've edited to fix that problem formatting the miliseconds field. Left the wrong line commeted. I hope it works now.

Comment: @Martin_911: Hours and minutes don't show when zero because I didn't see them in your example, but doesn't seem difficult to change its behaviour if needed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my english is bad sry.. I've been trying with 45 calls so it is working fine. The main goal is 500 calls but it seems it is enough. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { cmd = "date +%s.%N -d " }
NR%2  {
    cmd $0 | getline var1;
    next
}
{
    cmd $0 | getline var2;
    var3 = var2 - var1;
    print "Call " ++i, var3 " ms"
}
' file
Call 1 0.241 ms
Call 2 0.226 ms
Call 3 1.117 ms
Call 4 0.91 ms
Call 5 0.98 ms
```

Comment: +1 Good one-liner with a valuable help of the `date` external command.

Comment: I dont know how to say THANK YOU for everyone! Your post help me too much!

Comment: @Martin_911 : when you get to 16 points reputation, you can upvote all of these fine answers. Your question was very well formulated, you showed input, expected output, AND the code you tried so far. For future reference, note how @DanFergo reformatted your question to make it easier to read. The reformatting tools are at the top left of the input-text box. The 'B I | Globe \`\` {} ... thingy. Your language is fine.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not tied to awk:

```
to_epoch() { date -d "$1" "+%s.%N"; }
count=0
paste - - < input |
while read t1 t2; do
    ((count++))
    diff=$(printf "%s-%s\n" $(to_epoch "$t2") $(to_epoch "$t1") | bc -l)
    printf "Call %d %5.3f ms\n" $count $diff
done
```

Comment: I dont know how to say THANK YOU for everyone! Your post help me too much!